# Complex if statement never gets executed

Tags: c#

I have this long if statement that is checking for multiple things.  It never seems to execute the code in the curly brackets though.

It is checking two objects.

"currentEngineObject" is the object as it exists in the database.

"engineList" is the object that is passed into this method.

So I am trying to check to make sure that the SizeId is not empty and also has a value for both objects.

If they both have values, but they are not the same value, I want to set the "SizeId" of engineList to the  "SizeId" value that is in "currentEngineObject".

But even with test data, it never gets through the large `if` statement I have.

So I am wondering if there is a problem with my logic?  Like should I be using "Or" instead of "And"?

Here is my `if` block:

```
if ((currentEngineObject.SizeId.HasValue && currentEngineObject.SizeId.Value != Guid.Empty) 
    && (engineList.SizeId.HasValue && engineList.SizeId.Value != Guid.Empty)
    && (currentEngineObject.SizeId.Value != engineList.SizeId.Value))
{
    engineList.SizeId = currentEngineObject.SizeId.Value;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `GetValueOrDefault` method instead of `HasValue`/`Value`. And track your values with debugger

Comment: @Pavel or even `?.` / `??` operators

Comment: I'd personally use `if (currentEngineObject.SizeId.GetValueOrDefault() != default)`

Comment: Your condition seems correct (but it could be simplified as @PavelAnikhouski and @CaiusJard mentioned) can you set a breakpoint and inspect the data? BTW with only `&&` you don't need the parenthesis. `a && b && c && d == (a && b) && (c && d)`

Comment: What does _even with test data_ mean?  _I am wondering if there is a problem_  Is there  a unit test?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski so when using `currentEngineObject.SizeId.GetValueOrDefault` is the same has checking for both `Guid.Empty` and `null`? thanks!

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell [`GetValueOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.getvalueordefault?view=netcore-3.1) specs says _Retrieves the value of the current `Nullable<T>` object, or a default value._ Default value for `Guid` is `Guid.Empty`

Comment: Just to confirm, from your logic, which from your text, you only expect to override the `engineList.SizeId` if it already has one? But like others said, the condition matches your text, create a unit test along with sample inputs and expected outputs for that code.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski thanks for the link to `GetValueOrDefault`.  Maybe I'm not understanding the documentation, but how could `GetValueOrDefault` replace both the check to make sure it has a value and the check to make sure it's not empty?

Comment: @stuartd is `GetValueOrDefault() != default` equal to `!= Guid.Empty` && .HasValue`?  thanks!

Comment: I can't figure what is the type is SizeId? Could you please show your currentEngineObject class or part of it that include SizeId?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell yes - see https://dotnetfiddle.net/xucbF4

Comment: @Serge it is a guid. Thanks!

Comment: GUID doesnt have a HasValue Property. Do you use a string?

Comment: Try my last update, pls.

Comment: Try and debug this: what are the values of `currentEngineObject.SizeId` and `engineList.SizeId`? Are they *really* not null/empty and *really* different?

Comment: @stuartd what is `.Dump();` and is it needed in my case?  Thanks!

Comment: FYI `nullableGuid.GetValueOrDefault()` returns the `.Value` if it exists and `default(Guid)` if it doesn't (HasValue is false). And `default(Guid)` is the same as `Guid.Empty`. So you can ignore the null check and just check for empty

Comment: `.Dump()` is specific to that environment and basically `Console.WriteLine(..)` as extension method. You don't need it, it just shows results there

Comment: @HansKeﬆing Oh ok, so I can remove one of the checks.  So it would just simply be this? `if (currentEngineObject.SizeId.GetValueOrDefault() != Guid.Empty) { .. } `

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yes, simply that. As others have already tried to tell you ...

Comment: @HansKeﬆing thanks, I was just having a little bit of trouble understanding it, but I think I have it now.  thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ((currentEngineObject.SizeId.HasValue && currentEngineObject.SizeId.Value != Guid.Empty) 
    && (engineList.SizeId.HasValue && engineList.SizeId.Value != Guid.Empty)
    && !currentEngineObject.SizeId.Equals( engineList.SizeId)) ////Use equals
{
    engineList.SizeId =  currentEngineObject.SizeId;
}
```

Comment: GUID is a struct , not a class